# pip install -U mock : Error

Tags: python, unit-testing, pip, python-mock

I am trying to install mock for unit test a class in Python. I used the following command on terminal to install mock:

```
$ sudo pip install -U mock
```

I am getting the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-4u8kWt-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I am refererring to this in order to learn mocking for Python unit testing: https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/category/python/

I have Python 2.7.10 installed.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be running El Capitan.

From the following [link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165):

> This is because OS X El Capitan ships with six 1.4.1 installed already and when it attempts to uninstall it (because your package depends on six > 1.4.1) it doesn't have permission to do so because
>   System Integrity Protection doesn't allow even root to modify those
>   directories.

On most systems though, you'll likely want to use [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to create a custom environment and install dependencies for each project. This prevents you from trying to install things into the system version of python which may affect how your system runs.

```
cd source/directory
virtualenv env
. ./env/bin/activate
pip install mock
```

This also has the added benefit that each project can have it's own dependencies and you don't have to worry about version conflicts between projects.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I am running El Capitan. So if I create a `virtualenv` and then install mock using pip, will I be able to use mock for my current project which is not under `virtualenv`. Or will I have to migrate my project?

Comment: @KreenaMehta There's no migration for your project code. You would just setup the virtualenv, install all of your project's dependencies into the virtualenv, activate the virtualenv as shown above (or set it as the interpreter in PyCharm) and then your code will automatically run using the virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try.